# Cognito Trigger for Confirming Email Change

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, triggers, amazon-cognito

I would like to offer my users the possibility to change their email addresses. I require them to verify it afterwards (via cognito).

I am storing the users email address additionally in some other places, but only want to update it there once it's confirmed in cognito.

Can the **Post confirmation Lambda trigger** be used for that scenario? It only has two trigger sources: *PostConfirmation_ConfirmSignUp* and *PostConfirmation_ConfirmForgotPassword*. Does verifying an email address count as a *PostConfirmation_ConfirmSignUp* trigger source?